# How to put appwidget-provider declaration for android widget

Tags: android

I am studying android's sample Wiktonary in how to create a widget for android.

My questions is why it puts

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="146dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_message" />
```

in a file called wdiget_word.xml under res/xml? Instead of putting it under AndroidManifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [that is what you are supposed to do](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData).